# Using parseFloat() in different locales

Tags: javascript, locale

I have an input field that is formatted using `.toLocaleString()`.

Then I need to use `parseFloat()` on that value to convert it to a number.

To do this with a US locale, I simply use `value.replace(',','')` to strip out the decimals before executing the `parseFloat()`.

However this doesn't work in European locales in which the thousand separators and decimal points are inverted.

Is there a method of determining which locale your user is in and then whether to invert commas and decimals first?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse a string with a comma thousand separator to a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665884/how-can-i-parse-a-string-with-a-comma-thousand-separator-to-a-number)

Comment: can you provide some examples to understand it better

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Localization of input type number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13412204/9434800)

Comment: Unfortunately those other questions don't really address the issue, which is that the thousand separator could either be a comma or a decimal. @trincot's answer is a really good solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use `toLocaleString` to first see how an example number is converted to string, then learn from that output what the locale's separators are, and use that info to parse the string:

```js
function localeParseFloat(s, locale) {
    // Get the thousands and decimal separator characters used in the locale.
    let [,thousandsSeparator,,,,decimalSeparator] = 1111.1.toLocaleString(locale);
    // Remove thousand separators, and put a point where the decimal separator occurs
    s = Array.from(s, c => c === thousandsSeparator ? "" 
                         : c === decimalSeparator   ? "." : c).join("");
    // Now it can be parsed
    return parseFloat(s);
}

console.log(localeParseFloat("1.100,9")); // user's locale
console.log(localeParseFloat("1.100,9", "us")); // US locale
console.log(localeParseFloat("1.100,9", "nl")); // Dutch locale: reversed meaning of separators
// And the same but with separators switched:
console.log(localeParseFloat("1,100.9")); // user's locale
console.log(localeParseFloat("1,100.9", "us")); // US locale
console.log(localeParseFloat("1,100.9", "nl")); // Dutch locale: reversed meaning of separators
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot. It doesn't require mapping all possible locales and keep up with that.