# Is it possible to interchange between commas and points as decimal separators?

Tags: javascript

I have a calculator that is meant to calculate prices in Dollars and Euros and the biggest issue I'm facing here is the fact that using a comma as a decimal separator does not work with the `<input type='number'>` tag. I have read that browser language determines how this particular input type responds, but I was wondering if there was a way to alter that with JS.

```
function pplCalculator() {
    let endprice = document.getElementById('ppl-calculator--endprice');
    let margin = document.getElementById('ppl-calculator--margin');
    let basePrice = document.getElementById('ppl-calculator--val');
    let locale = document.querySelector('html').getAttribute('lang'); 
    let config = {
        dollar: {
            retailDefault: 18.99,
            basePrice: 13.99,
        },
        euro: {
            retailDefault: 19.99,
            basePrice: 14.99
        }
    }
    let currency = locale === 'en-US' ? 'dollar' : 'euro';

    function calculatorInit(){
        endprice.value = config[currency].retailDefault;
        basePrice.textContent = config[currency].basePrice;
        margin.textContent = (endprice.value - basePrice.textContent).toLocaleString(locale);
    }

    function updateCalculator(target, events, handler){
        events.map(function(event){
            target.addEventListener(event, () => {
                    let userInput = endprice.value;
                    let marginValue = userInput - basePrice.textContent;

                    if (marginValue > 0) {
                        margin.textContent = marginValue.toLocaleString(locale);
                    } else {
                        margin.textContent = 0;
                    }
            });
        })
    }
    calculatorInit();
    updateCalculator(endprice, ['keyup','change']);
}
pplCalculator();
```

This is my HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td><strong>Retail Price</strong></td>
      <td><input id="ppl-calculator--endprice" type="number"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><strong>Profit</strong></td>
      <td><p id="ppl-calculator--margin"></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><strong>Base Price</strong></td>
      <td><p id="ppl-calculator--val"></p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The page has a language switcher that uses OctoberCMS's activeLocale to change the language attribute in my HTML tag. The `locale` var uses that information.

The actual calculation works fine, but I can't seem to figure out how to switch to EU formatting for the Euros both on the input and in the Init function. Using `element.toLocaleString()` creates a string (which is fine for displaying output), but obviously does not work with input.

What would be the best way to accommodate both decimal separators?

I also want to add; I would like to avoid having to build a spinner box to increase and decrease the numbers if at all possible hence the Number input field instead of Text. If it is completely unavoidable, I suppose it's the way to go, but I wanted to double check first.

Comment: Just string-replace the commas in to period and if a currency uses a silly deliminator then string-replace it back when finished.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Localization of input type number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412204/localization-of-input-type-number)

Comment: @aloisdgmovingtocodidact.com yes and no. I was literally just reading through that and I suppose it answers my question on whether or not the language can be altered outside of Browser Language, but it doesn't solve my issue because I do need the up and down buttons as well. Perhaps I need to build that myself - something I'd really like to avoid if I can.

Comment: <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+([\.|,][0-9]{1,2})?" name="amount">
use input type text instad of number.