# How to handle decimal input values in a globalized MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, number-formatting, globalization

Currently trying to rework a .NET 4.8 MVC application to support globalization (needs to support both English and French). So far, everything has been working fine.

The issue, however, is with decimal input. This is a financial application, so it is important that I deal with input boxes that are set to `type="number"`. Strictly speaking, I know that the value `15000,25` is not considered a number, and will not convert implicitly to a decimal (the backing field data type that I use in my view model). With this in mind, I have a custom model binder:

```cs
public class DecimalModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (valueProviderResult == null)
        {
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueProviderResult.AttemptedValue))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var result = decimal.TryParse(valueProviderResult.AttemptedValue, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out decimal covertedOutput);

        if (result)
        {
            return covertedOutput;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

This model binder is then registered in the Global.asax file. The above appears to work to an extent...especially in Firefox, in that I can enter 15000,25 into a form input and what happens on the backend is that 15000.25 is recorded in the database.

This is a different story in chrome, as

1. I cannot enter 15000,25 as a value, only decimal point based numbers
   and
2. on the reload from the server - chrome will try and take 15000.25 and parse it as 15000,25 in the input...which fails, with the error:

> The specified value "15000,25" cannot be parsed, or is out of range

**My question is this** - should I force users to always deal with true decimal based numbers? So stop them from entering 15000,25 but allow 15000.25? or is there a way around this / best practice that I'm just not seeing?

Here is the decimal field that I'm working with. Both the form control and the view model property:

```html
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SellAmount, "{0:f2}", new {min = "0", type = "number", step = "1000" })
```

```cs
public decimal? SellAmount { get; set; }
```

Comment: You already have one close vote for opinionated question. You may want to consider changing that title, _quick_. And in future avoid "Best way to", "Most efficient ..." type of titles. What you are asking is "How to ..." - that allows users to suggest _their_ preferred way to solve the problem you are having. If one of those is particularly "better" or "worse" _may_ sometimes be objectively measurable but most of the time it "depends".

Comment: I am not versed in asp.net-mvc but will the context give you a client culture? If so, you need to use that for parsing instead of the invariant culture.

Comment: @Fildor thanks for the tip. It was not my intention to ask an annoying question…but I realize the title was a poor choice. As for your next comment…I use invariant culture to remove the localized adulteration of the decimal value. This is more of an issue with the front end (I believe).

Comment: I am not sure if, but it sounds like the text input does not seem to adapt for client culture even when put to "number" type...

Comment: And you didn't ask an annoying question :) just "best way" triggers some people to close vote for "opinionated" without even reading the question.

Comment: Digging through this, it appears that what i'm trying to do is not possible with input type=number https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412204/localization-of-input-type-number